# Traversing states of a automaton in linear time and space complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, automata, space-complexity, graph-traversal

How can states of a automaton being traversed in linear time and space complexity? How would the states/transitions be expressed as data structures?

Also, is there a algorithm for converting a NFA to a DFA in linear time and space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation depends on the exact application. In general case, you can always implement it as a node with multiple outgoing links. In this case, transitioning is O(1).

However, you could implement using a matrix. Especially when the transitions are dense.

Comment: Using the outgoing links, wouldn't it require a recursive algorithm or a stack for the parents? 

Also, wouldn't the nodes be visited first in order to create a matrix assuming that the automaton will be build within the application?

Comment: @Tim What are you trying to do again? Are you trying to test if a particular sequence was generated by an automaton?